# What "cache the residuals" means in an optimization algorithm?

Tags: c, machine-learning, optimization, svd

I am reading [this](https://sifter.org/simon/journal/20061211.html) about the Netflix challenge (2006). At some point he says:

> For efficiency's sake, cache the residuals (all 100 million of them) so when you're training feature 72 you don't have to wait for predictRating() to re-compute the contributions of the previous 71 features. You will need 2 Gig of ram, a C compiler, and good programming habits to do this.

What does it mean to cache the residuals? How can you avoid re-compute all the residuals when you change the value of the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that instead of recomputing parts of the solution each time, as the part is needed, you should first lookup in a cache of the computed value.  If it is present, there is no need to recompute it, it is just used.  If it is not present, it is computed, stored in the cache, and used.

So let's say we are computing the sum of three factorial numbers.  Every factorial number is computed by the formula F(x) = x * F(x-1) or F(0) = 1.  So if you had to find F(7) + F(3) + F(9), F(7) would cache F(7) through F(0) and F(3) would compute nothing, being looked up from the previous cached values.  Likewise F(9) would be computed from F(8) also being computed from F(7) which would not be computed, being looked up from the cache.

Residuals are any part of a computation used in the process of obtaining a final answer.